# Sum column in dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamic table which calculates the a total column at the end of each row depending on input values but I cannot seem to get the total of this row?

I create my table with:

```js
function calc() {
    var td = document.querySelectorAll('#item_table > tr > td:last-child');
    
    var stotal = [].reduce.call(td, function(a, b) {
        return a + parseInt(b.innerText);
    }, 0);
    
    document.getElementById('sub_total').innerText = stotal;
}

$(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
      var html = '';
      html += '<tr>';
      html += '<td><input type="number" min="0" value="0" name="item_name[]" oninput="calc();calcSub()" class="form-control item_name" size="16" /></td>';
      html += '<td><input type="number" min="0" value="0" name="item_quantity[]" oninput="calc()" class="form-control item_quantity" /></td>';
      html += '<td><input type="number" min="0" value="0" name="item_unit[]" oninput="calc()" class="form-control item_unit" /></td>';
      //NEW ONES!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
      html += '<td><select name="item_glass[]" oninput="calc()" class="form-control item_glass"><option>Select Glass Type</option><?php echo fill_unit_select_box($connect); ?></select></td>';
      html += '<td><select name="item_splash[]" oninput="calc()" class="form-control item_splash"><option value="0">Select Splash</option><?php echo fill_unit_select_box3($connect); ?></select></td>';
      html += '<td><input type="text" value="-" name="item_colour[]" oninput="calc()" class="form-control item_colour" /></td>';
    
      html += '<td><input type="number" min="0" value="0" oninput="calc()" name="item_HQuan[]" class="form-control item_HQuan" /></td>';
      html += '<td><select name="item_HDiam[]" oninput="calc()" class="form-control item_HDiam"><option value="0">Select Hole Diameter</option><?php echo fill_unit_select_box2($connect); ?></select></td>';
      html += '<td><input type="number" min="0" value="0" oninput="calc()" name="item_CQuan[]" class="form-control item_CQuan" /></td>';
    
      //Total
      html += '<td><input type="text" value="0.0" name="item_Total[]" id="item_Total[]" class="form-control item_Total" disabled/></td>';
    
    
      html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove">Delete Item<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';
      $('#item_table').append(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered" id="item_table">
      <tr id="titles">
       <th>Quantity</th>
       <th>Width</th>
       <th>Height</th>
       <th>Glass Type</th>
       <th>Sparkle or Glaze</th>
       <th>Colour Code</th>
       <th>Hole Quantity</th>
       <th>Hole Diameter</th>
       <th>Cut-out Quantity</th>
       <th>Item cost £ (excl. Vat)</th>
    
    
       <th><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-sm add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Add Item</button></th>
      </tr>
     </table>

 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="job_ref">Sub Total</label>
  <input type="text" id="sub_total"  class="form-control sub_total" name="sub_total" placeholder="0" value="0" readonly/>
 </div>
```

Another thing tried but always equal to 0 regardless of the input:

```
function calcSub(){


     var cls = document.getElementById("item_Total[]").getElementsByTagName("td");
      var sum = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < cls.length; i++){
          if(cls[i].className == "countable"){
              sum += isNaN(cls[i].value) ? 0 : parseInt(cls[i].value);
          }
      }
      document.getElementById('sub_total').value = sum;

   };
```

Is their anyway to do this I cant figure it out?

Comment: where you define `calc()` function?

Comment: Above the function for creating dynamic tables

Comment: Does your table have `tbody`??

Comment: I have updated my post to inclue the table and have tried it without tbody - still the same output

Comment: How do you want it to be calculated? Every time the user clicks the Add Item button? or what?

Comment: Everytime the total column changes, the sub tota should update

Comment: insert `calcSub` function too

Comment: Where should the result of the calculation be displayed?

Comment: @FDavidov i have updated my question with another possivle solution which highlights where the answer should go

Comment: I don't see in your code any element whose id is `"sub_total"`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @FDavidov at the bottom of the table?

Comment: I see `item_Total`, not `sub_total`. In fact, I searched the page and `sub_total` cannot be found anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   function calcSub(){

    var totalPrice = 0;
    $(".item_Total").each(function(){
        totalPrice += parseInt($(this).val());
        $(".sub_total").val(totalPrice);
    });
```

Answer driven from post: [How to sum values from table column and update when remove/add new row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41656542/how-to-sum-values-from-table-column-and-update-when-remove-add-new-row)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this code

```js
$(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
     var html = '';
      html += '<tr>';
      html += '<td><input type="number" min="0" value="0" name="item_name[]" class="form-control item_name" size="16" /></td>';
      html += '<td><input type="number" min="0" value="0" name="item_quantity[]" class="form-control item_quantity" /></td>';
      html += '<td><input type="number" min="0" value="0" name="item_unit[]" class="form-control item_unit" /></td>';
      //NEW ONES!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
      html += '<td><select name="item_glass[]" class="form-control item_glass"><option>Select Glass Type</option><?php echo fill_unit_select_box($connect); ?></select></td>';
      html += '<td><select name="item_splash[]" class="form-control item_splash"><option value="0">Select Splash</option><?php echo fill_unit_select_box3($connect); ?></select></td>';
      html += '<td><input type="text" value="-" name="item_colour[]" class="form-control item_colour" /></td>';
    
      html += '<td><input type="number" min="0" value="0" name="item_HQuan[]" class="form-control item_HQuan" /></td>';
      html += '<td><select name="item_HDiam[]" class="form-control item_HDiam"><option value="0">Select Hole Diameter</option><?php echo fill_unit_select_box2($connect); ?></select></td>';
      html += '<td><input type="number" min="0" value="0" name="item_CQuan[]" class="form-control item_CQuan" /></td>';
    
      //Total
      html += '<td><input type="text" value="0.0" name="item_Total[]" id="item_Total[]" class="form-control item_Total" disabled/></td>';
    
    
      html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove">Delete Item<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';
      $('#item_table').append(html);
});

$(document).on('change', 'input', function() {
  $("table tr").each(function(ind, el) {
   var sum = 0; $(this).find("input:not(:last)").each(function(indx, ele) {
     sum += $(ele).val(); 
    });
    $(this).find("input").last().val(sum);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered" id="item_table">
  <tr id="titles">
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Width</th>
    <th>Height</th>
    <th>Glass Type</th>
    <th>Sparkle or Glaze</th>
    <th>Colour Code</th>
    <th>Hole Quantity</th>
    <th>Hole Diameter</th>
    <th>Cut-out Quantity</th>
    <th>Item cost £ (excl. Vat)</th>

    <th><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-sm add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Add Item</button></th>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="job_ref">Sub Total</label>
  <input type="text" id="sub_total" class="form-control sub_total" name="sub_total" placeholder="0" value="0" readonly/>
</div>
```

But consider these:

> 1-create a class for columns you want to be calculated and modify its jquery selector.
>
> 2-ensure the input values always are numeric, then convert them into `Number`.
>
> 3-for the `Sub Total` insert special jquery code you want. (I did not add that, because I don't know how exactly calculate its value)